# How programmably wait until the process will start the endpoint

Tags: node.js, process, timeout, delay

I have created a [small example application](https://gitlab.com/borysl/mindoc/pipelines/58201453) in node.js with unit tests and acceptance tests here

Both unit and acceptance tests are run inside mocha process. Acceptance tests start from forking the process and basically running the server on before() method. after() method stops the process and

```
before((initialized) => {
  console.log('before script');
  serverProcess = child_process.fork('server.js');
  serverProcess.on('close', function (code) {  
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);  
});
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('1s elapsed');
  initialized();
}, 1000);
```

The code without any delays works on my local gitlab-runner, however on server it's not always the case, so I have added delay - wait for a while until the server will start.
    Empirically I have found that 1s is enough and .5s is not.
    However, I would like to know what should I do to make sure that the server is.

```
Are there any solutions to run server, execute the tests and shutdown the server that works on Linux, Windows, docker and outside of it?
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good help about [how to communicate between fork processes](https://medium.com/@NorbertdeLangen/communicating-between-nodejs-processes-4e68be42b917).

The idea will be to send a message from the child saying to it's dad (I am ready!). Then the dad will continue is work.

**Example :**

```
before((initialized) => {
  serverProcess = child_process.fork('server.js');

  serverProcess.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
  });

  serverProcess.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
  });

  // We add a backup plan. If it takes too long to launch, throw
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    initialized(new Error('tiemout');
  }, 30000);

  // Cait for the child to send a message to us
  serverProcess.on('message', function(str) {
    if (str === 'init done') {
      clearTimeout(timeout);

      // server.js got successfully initialized
      initialized();
    }
  });
});
```

---

```
// To add inside of your server.js listen
if (process.send) {
  process.send("init done");
}
```